# Jmeter - Loop through the array defined from 'User Defined Variables'

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I try to Loop scenario for 2 times fetching data from array.

My use case is: I want to create user, for multiple countries, so instead of coping the case, I want to implement loop logic.

So far a tried like, but without success:

1. from here I want to fetch data

//JSR223 PreProcessor

```
String[] varArray = {"US", "UK"};
idx = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("loopCounter"))-1;
vars.put("myVariable", varArray[idx]);
```

[image]

2. counter logic:
   [image]
3. Whole script, which is chain of multiple API calls, and i want to use fetch data, only a single call.

[image]

Result: 
I got `null`, if I try to use fetch variable.

```
Script37.groovy: 1: unexpected token: US @ line 1, column 22.
   String[] varArray = {"US", "UK"};
```

Comment: just edit my post, i got null for the fetched variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define `countries` variable via [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables-Using-User-Defined-Variables) like:

   [image]
2. In the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) you can dynamically get the array length via [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function as:

   ```
   ${__groovy(vars.get('countries').split().size(),)}
   ```

   [image]
3. Wherever you want inside the Loop Controller you can reference the "current" country for the given loop as:

   ```
   ${__groovy(vars.get('countries').split()[vars.get('__jm__Loop Controller__idx') as int],)}
   ```

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use square brackets for java array when using [Apache Groovy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_arrays):

```
String[] varArray = ["US", "UK"];
```

If you were using Beanshell/Java scripting language, you code will work

```
String[] varArray = {"US", "UK"};
```

Comment: OK, error is gone. Just test is not run two times (based on two fetched variable) What should be used in Loop controller variable field?

Comment: @vlatko606 `${loopCounter}` in Loop Count

Comment: @vlatko606 didn't my answer helped? Loop count can be a number 2 in your case

Comment: No, i still did not managed to tell 'Loop Controller' how much times to run.If i use ${loopCounter}, my 'Loop Controller' is not running at all. IF i use static number into 'Loop Controller' ex:2, it runs 2 times. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: @vlatko606 Loop count can be a number 2 in your case

Comment: i know, but say i add more elements to the array, then this number get increased. how can 'Loop Controller' knows how many times to run?

Comment: `vars.put("myVariable", String.valueOf( varArray.length));`